# Unable to utilize the Printing API in Rho 4.1

Tags: android, bluetooth, rhomobile

I have upgraded to Rho 4.1 in attempts to utilize the new Printing API.  I have had zero success.  I have attempted both the JS samples and a rough Ruby implementation to connect to my Bluetooth printer.

I have added the "printing" extension to my build.yml.  I receive the following errors when attempting to call into the API...

JS implementation:
Error when calling "Rho.Printer.searchPrinters": TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Rho.Printer.searchPrinters')

Ruby implementation:
When attempting to call "Rho::Printer.searchPrinters": I receive "Error: uninitialized constant Rho::Printer".

This project was actually created using 2.2.0 and upgraded to 4.1 just recently.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [Rhodes test repository available on github](https://github.com/rhomobile/RMS-Testing/tree/master/manual/other/ComplianceTest_Ruby). There's some sample code testing the Printer APIs that you can use to understand what you need to implement.

Pay attention to the options used by the searchPrintes method:

```
Rho::Printer.searchPrinters({}, url_for(:action => :searchPrinters_callback))
```

Should be useful try to use the API in a new v4.1 apps, to check that everything is working for you and then implement the feature in your application, porting it from Rhodes v2.2 to v4.1